# Using date pipe in a conditional expression - Angular 2

Tags: angular

With the follow expression I'm expecting for Angular to interpolate a date (if not null) through the date pipe, but I get the proceeding error.

```
{{charge.offenseDate ? charge.offenseDate | date : 'No date'}}

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression {{charge.offenseDate ? charge.offenseDate | date : 'No Date' }} requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression
```

Is what I'm expecting possible, or just a...*pipe dream* :)

Comment: Have you tried `{{charge.offenseDate ? (charge.offenseDate | date) : 'No date'}}`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no I didn't think to try that, but I just did, and it worked. If you pop it in as an answer I'll be glad to accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Just wrap it with `()`

```
{{charge.offenseDate ? (charge.offenseDate | date) : 'No date'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For more than one pipe u can use

```
text="{{ item.COURSE_REGED == 0 ?  ('EDU_COURSE_SIGNUP'| translate ) +(item.COURSE_COST | number)+ ('PUP_CURRENCY_NAME' | translate)   : ('EDU_COURSE_SIGNED_UP'| translate) }}"
```